# scanf is being skipped: how to make it take user's input?

Tags: char, scanf

I recently had to create a program that recreates the Monty Hall problem. I have to ask a user to choose a door in between 1 and 3. I then choose, randomly, which door has the prize behind it. Once done, I reveal a door with no prize to the user, at which point he can either choose to keep his original door or change it. This is where my problem occurs. The following bloc of code (all my variables have been initialised previously) is when I ask the user to either keep the original door or to change it. For some unkown reason, the program does not wait for the user to input his choice; instead, it skips the scanf("%c", &choice). I have no clue howcome this happens, would someone be able to elucidate this mistery? Thank you :)

```
int portes[] = {0,0,0};
        srand(time(0));
        winning_door= rand()%3;
        doors[winning_door] = 1;
        printf("\nChoose a door:\n");
        scanf("%d", &chosen_door);

        for(i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            if(doors[i] == 0 && i != (chosen_door-1))
            {
                printf("The door number %d is empty!\n", i+1);
                printf("\nWould you like to change doors? Enter 'y' for yes and 'n' for no.\n");
                scanf("%c", &choice);
                break;
            }
        }
```

In this code, the scanf("%c", &choice); is completely ignored and the program skips to the next part!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `%c` directive to scanf reads a single character **WITHOUT** skipping whitespace.  So in your case, it will read the newline still hanging on the input after the first `Choose a door` question/answer.  You can instead use `%1s` to read a single non-whitespace character (and ignore all whitespace), which will skip over the left-over newline and any blanks the user might enter, returning the first "real" character they enter.  If you do, however, you'll need to declare choice as an array of two characters (`char choice[2]`), as scanf will write a NULL byte after the single character read.

Alternately, you can add a space to the format before the `%c` (so it would be `scanf(" %c", &choice)`), which explicitly skips all whitespace characters.

Comment: Thanks, I am able do run the program properly!